# Chef will not checkout development branch from git

Tags: git, chef-infra

Below is my code for checking out my repo.  I want the development branch in my chef dev environment.

```
git "/home/ubuntu/workspace/repo" do                            
    repository "git@github.com:me/repo.git"
    revision "development"                                 
    action :sync                                     
    user "root"                                                                  
end
```

when I look at the checkout branch I get:

```
* deploy
  master
```

if I run git checkout development on the box I get:

```
deploy
* development
  master
```

So....how do I get git to checkout my dev branch from chef?

I am using the example from the chef wiki. [chef wiki git example](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource)

```
if node.chef_environment == "QA"
    branch_name = "staging"
else
    branch_name = "master"
end

git "/home/user/deployment" do                            
    repository "git@github.com:gitsite/deployment.git"
    revision branch_name                                  
    action :sync                                     
    user "user"                                    
    group "test"                                      
end
```

Comment: I can't find the docs that specify what goes in the 'git' closure above, but, I have a gut feeling that 'revision' isn't what you want.  Generally 'revision' points to a particular SHA, not a branch.  Is there another attribute that could possibly be it?

Comment: Hi, I added the source from the chef wiki

Comment: I have the exact same issue...

Answer (score 11):

Your development branch gets deployed. It is only named `deploy` because chef checks out into a local branch instead of a detached HEAD.

#### The git provider

Here's an excerpt from the actual code:

```
#File: chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/provider/git.rb
def checkout                                                              
  sha_ref = target_revision                                               
  # checkout into a local branch rather than a detached HEAD              
  shell_out!("git checkout -b deploy #{sha_ref}", run_options(:cwd => @new_resource.destination))
  Chef::Log.info "#{@new_resource} checked out branch: #{@new_resource.revision} reference: #{sha_ref}"
end
```

You'd also see an info messages within your chef client's log from which the deployed branch can be seen:

```
[Sun, 01 Jul 2012 18:07:40 +0200] INFO: git[/usr/local/rbenv] checked out branch: master reference: 6778c8e905d774d4dc70724c455e6fcff4c1d3e1
```

#### Documentation

Also, the link to the docs in your question clearly says:

> Keep in mind that if you use the command "git status" after running this recipe it will return the branch name as "deploy" regardless, as this is a default value. You should be able to see it checking out the correct branch when you run chef-client with debugging on:
>
> sudo chef-client -l debug

More information on a detached HEAD state can be found e.g. at AlBlue's [blog](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-detached-heads.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to git resource page in chef docs:
http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html

Use the following attribute:

```
checkout_branch

Use to specify the name of a branch to be checked out. Default value: deploy.
```

So you would want to do this:

```
git "/home/ubuntu/workspace/repo" do                            
    repository "git@github.com:me/repo.git"
    revision "development"                                 
    checkout_branch 'development'
    action :sync                                     
    user "root"                                                                  
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate answer. I tried this and it looks like it will result in two branches - "deploy" and "development" - with the deploy branch selected.

Answer (score 3):

for anyone still having issues with this problem, you can use enable_checkout to false.  This will leave your branch at master and won't break when you set checkout_branch to master.

```
git "/home/user/deployment" do
   repository "git@github.com:gitsite/deployment.git"
   revision branch_name
   checkout_branch branch_name
   enable_checkout false
   action :sync
   user "user"
   group "test"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

as fooforge said:

Basically chef will say

`git checkout -b deploy remote/branch`

if you do a `git log` you will see the commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to push back to your original development branch, ( say you are using chef deploy to provision your app, but you are making changes in-situ and want to commit your changes) you can do the following

```
git push origin deploy:development
```